# How to get OpenID 2.0 identifiers using Google API PHP Client

Tags: google-api-php-client

I'm trying to migrate from OpenID 2.0 to OpenID Connect using the library found at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. I've got the example code from the bottom of https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app working but I can't figure out how to use the library to get the OpenID 2.0 identifiers.

Most of the documentation on Google recommends using these libraries, but only gives migration instructions pertaining to the HTTP requests. I've spent hours trying to figure this out but I'm just not having any luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out (and boy was it annoying). Here's what I did:

After

```
$client = new Google_Client();
```

I added

```
$client->setOpenidRealm('http://domain');
```

I change the scope to

```
$client->addScope("openid profile ".Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_PROFILE);
```

Then once I had an access token I used

```
$token_data=$client->verifyIdToken()->getAttributes();
```

Which returns an array with the useful information which is explained in detail in a table at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#server-flow

I hope this saves someone out there from the frustration I experienced.